# How to iterate over azure.core.paging.ItemPaged?

Tags: python, azure, enums, iterator, enumerate

I have an iterator object `<iterator object azure.core.paging.ItemPaged at 0x7fdb309c02b0>`. When I iterate over it for a first time (see code below), it prints the results. However, when I execute this code a second time, it prints nothing.

```
for i, r in enumerate(result):
   print(r)
```

What is wrong in my code? Do I need to somehow reset the enumerator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the `iterator` in python.

If you want the iterator still work in the 2nd time, you can use [itertools.tee()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) function to create a second version of your iterator. Like below:

```
from itertools import tee

#use the tee() function to create another version of iterator. here, it's result_backup
result, result_backup = tee(result)

print("**first iterate**")

for i, r in enumerate(result):
    print(r)


print("**second iterate**")

#in the 2nd time, you can use result_backup
for i, r in enumerate(result_backup):
    print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your solution but the program faced error:
"Parsed api-version 2022-05-13 is not available. Please use one of the following versions: 2022-04-20-preview,0.1-preview"
How I can change the api-version in python?